# Wrong cookie expiration date

Tags: c#, cookies

I have a problem on setting cookie Expiration Date from C# web-application (on a shared Windows-Hosting server, Plesk, where is no function to change Time-Zone - in this package).
When I set cookie *Value* and *Expiration Date* with the same DateTime value, Value is right, but Expiration Date is with added hours (+9 hours):

```
Cookie Info:
Value: 16/06/2018 17:02:11
Expires: 17.06.2018, 02:02:11
```

In my case, I'm using Windows-Hosting from country, which is not from my location (I also tried to upload this project with no changes, on Windows-Hosting server, Plesk, located in my country, where is set my Time-Zone, and cookie *Value* and *Expiration Date* was the same). I want to use time, alternate in my country, in the whole web-application (in cookie Value and Expiration Date too), so I'm using UTC time with setting location destination:

`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "Georgian Standard Time")`

On foreign country's Plesk, destination id is 'Central Standard Time'.

I'm using code below, to set this test cookie:

```
var date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "Georgian Standard Time");
var cookie = new HttpCookie("TestCookie", date.ToString());
cookie.Expires = date;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

My question and problem is, why cookie Expiration Date is not the one, I'm setting from back-end code, up here?

Thanks everyone for help..

Comment: Time on a computer is always store as UTC.  The Timezone setting in the computer convert the UTC to local timezone.  So you want the cookie expiration to be a DateTime object which will automatically be in UTC.  Then when the cookie is transmitted it will also be as UTC.  The cookie expiration time will always be the same no matter what timezone a PC is located.  It doesn't use the computer time.  So if a cookies is set to expire at midnight UTC then in NYC it will expire a 7:00 PM.  If the cookie expires at 5:00AM UTC then in NYC it will expire at midnight.

Comment: So, is there any way to set Expiration Date with static value I want (without changes with computer, localization or any other mechanism..)?

Comment: You would need the timezone of the computer that is sending the request to return the cookie expiration date in the same timezone.

Comment: So, taking into account your answers, I've done the next: I use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "Georgian Standard Time") in project, but I use DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), to set cookie Expiration Date. I think it is one of the ways to do it.. Thanks for answers.